# Persistent HTTPS connection in Adobe AIR

Tags: rest, firebase, actionscript-3, https, air

Question:
How can I make a persistent connection to a HTTPS REST API from Adobe AIR?

Background:
I am using the Firebase Realtime Database to power a game made in Adobe AIR(version 31) for iOS, Android & Desktop. It works great but I get a TLS handshake overhead of 15kb on each request I make to the server because it is making a new connection on reach request. That adds up to about 99% of my server costs at the moment. The closest thing to a solution I have found is to maybe use the SecureSocket class and use that to make HTTPS requests but can't figure out how to do that. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You can have persistent connection with **URLStream** class (HTTP, incoming only) or **Socket** class (TCP, full duplex).

Comment: Can you guide me to how to use the Socket class to connect to a REST API like Firebase? I guess Secure Socket would be more suitable here since it is HTTPS.

Comment: Nope, never worked with them ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Instead of using all that overhead of a database and persistent connections, simply use xml. Store the shared data in xml. Loading and processing xml is as light as possible. No special connections, no serverside processing, etc. Clients submit to php or whatever, php opens and updates the xml files.